# Oracle quotes issue . Error missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle, quotes

INSERT INTO myTable (SELECT 2, mem_type_actor ('Phillip D'Onofrio ,Val Kilmer') FROM DUAL)

I want to insert into myTable these records but because of the quotes of D'Onofrio I get the error:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

How can I fix it ?

I edit my question:

Infact I don't take records like that, I have these sql codes:

```
 M_TERMS=Rocky,Carroll ; Chris,O'Donnell ; Daniela,Ruah ;
 M_STR:=REPLACE(REPLACE(''''||M_TERMS||'''',',',' '),';',','); 
 M_SQL:='INSERT INTO myTable (SELECT '||M_ID||' , mem_type_actor ('||M_STR||') FROM DUAL)';
```

So when a record is like that O'Donnell  , ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
occurs

Answer (score 4):

You should use

```
INSERT INTO myTable 
    (SELECT 2, mem_type_actor ('Phillip D''Onofrio ,Val Kilmer') FROM DUAL)
```

using two single quotes in place of one inside string.

Answer (score 3):

Use two single quote signs: `D''Onofrio`.

Answer (score 3):

Or use Oracle's q-quote operator: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/PlsqlEnhancements10g.php#quoting_mechanism_for_string_literals

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of using quotation marks in the oracle database 19c:

- Using `Q`(quotation) before the beginning of the string and `!` at the start and end of the string.

```
SELECT Q!' Today is my mother's birthday!' FROM DUAL;
```

- Using double quotations(`'` `'`) marks. This is just a workaround.

```
SELECT 'Today is my mother''s birthday' FROM DUAL;
```

I hope this would have answered this question regarding quotation marks in the oracle database.

Comment: `!` is a delimiter here, you can also use `( )`, `[ ]`, `< >`, etc. here.